# How to fill Array for use in while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, meteor, while-loop

this is my code...

```
var test = "";
        Playerslist.find().map(function(doc) {
          test += doc.SpielerID;
        });

        return [test];
```

When I execude this piece of code, I will get 105 110. (SpielerID 105, 110)
After this I must build a while loop. I think to use this in the while loop I need an array for getting the SpielerID Nums? [105], [110] How to build such an array for later use in a while loop and how can I achieve the right positions?

Answer (score 1):

This question isn't clear, although assuming you want an array of IDs, starting with an array of objects (eg. `Playerslist.find()` returns an array like `[{...}, {...}]`), you can simply map as follows:

```js
var ids = Playerslist.find().map(function (doc) { 
  return doc.SpielerID;
});

console.log(ids);  // prints [105, 110]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, just return `doc.SpielerID` directly from the map:

```
    return Playerslist.find().map(function(doc) {
      return doc.SpielerID;
    });
```

... should yield `[ID1, ID2, ... IDN]`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Now let's have a look on my code...
...
          spielerPkt += test[i] + ":" + total + ", ";
          i++;
        }
        return spielerPkt;
And the html looks like <body> {{outputFunction}} </body>. At the moment the result returns like  105:5.5, 110:0,   . But I want to have this: 105:5.5 <linebreak> 110:0 What I have to do?